# How to load md2 file with OpenGL(GLUT)

Tags: opengl, blender-2.49

I have created a solid sphere with texture and without animation in Blender.I have exported it in md2 file format.Now I want to load it with OpenGL using c++.Iam new in programming,I have learned about md2 file formate but can't write code to load it so please provide me code or any site link where I will get code.
Thanks you

Comment: -1: Due to an obvious lack of research effort. It would be better to try to write an MD2 loader, or to track down an MD2 loader, run into a problem, and then ask us about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is "merely" a drawing API (though a powerfull one). It doesn't deal with loading files, be it geometry or images, managing scenes or other high level stuff. That's all your responsibility.

You can not load MD2 files *using* OpenGL, but you can of course load MD2 files using a MD2 file loader/parser and feed the extracted data *to* OpenGL. That's a big difference. If those concepts are very new to you I suggest you first start with getting the grips on OpenGL itself by following some tutorials: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides

Once you're firm with OpenGL itself you may either write your own MD2 parser, or use some third party library for doing so. But don't get ahead of yourself, save yourself that frustration.